# C# best way to mark derivative class instances

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose you have a class called Food, and you have derivative classes called Banana and Apple and Orange.  You have a FoodProcessor method somewhere, which for the most part, can process any type of Food, but occasionally needs to know what type of Food it is processing, in order to do something type-specific, such as peel the Banana, core the Apple, or squeeze the Orange.

So your FoodProcessor takes Food arguments.  What's the best way for your FoodProcessor to detect the specific derivative type of the Food instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing the type of an object, I like to use the `is` keyword, like this:

```
if(myFood is Bannana)
  Peel((Bannana)myFood);
```

I prefer [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) because it will also check whether the object implements an interface.

And speaking of interfaces, you may want to consider using interfaces if you've got certain types that perform specific actions.  Checking against a specific type requires knowledge of the different types that may be used, however, if you check against an interface, new types can emerge that implement this interface without you needing to change your code to handle them:

```
if(myFood is IPeelable)
  Peel((IPeelable)myFood)
else if(myFood is ICoreable)
  Core((ICoreable)myFood)
```

If you look for specific types, you'll need to know every possible type now, and in the future, which is not very scalable.

This of course assumes you don't want to use straight polymorphism, as one of the other answers describes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use polymorphism, each `Food` subclass will define a method `process()` and the `FoodProcessor` class will simply call that method.

FoodProcessor

```
public void process(Food f) {
    f.process(); 
}
```

Apple

```
public void process() {
    Console.WriteLine("Core the apple.");
}
```

Banana

```
public void process() {
    Console.WriteLine("Peel the banana.");
}
```

Orange

```
public void process() {
    Console.WriteLine("Squeeze the orange.");
}
```

In this way you take advantage of the inheritance relationship between Food and its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it abstract and implement it in each food:

```
abstract class Food {
    public abstract void Prepare();
}

class Banana : Food {
    public override void Prepare() {
        Peel();
    }
}

class Apple : Food {
    public override void Prepare() {
        Core();
    }
}
```

Then you would have:

```
class FoodProcessor {
    public void Process(Food food) {
        food.Prepare(); // preparation of the food
        food.Process();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the polymorphism answer because you're basically telling the Food to go process itself.  (In some cases, that would be great, but not what I'm looking for in this question.)  It looks like the "is" keyword is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey That was just an example. In my above example, you could simply call `Prepare` then continue processing the food in the food processor's `Process` method.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey More importantly, I feel like this design is heading in the direction of SRP where the Food is not much more than a data structure and the OP will add a class for each responsibility such as Preparing, Processing, Post Processing etc... which is equivalent to discarding encapsulation , which is even more fundamental than SRP rule. Not to mention the tight coupling and lack of scalability in using the `is` operator for specific types' processing, which could just cleanly be encapsulated in the derived types themselves. FWIW

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Add an edit to suggest an interface and you get my upvote =P He hasn't given any reason to suggest we really need a base abstract class which has the potential pitfall of locking us into a specific abstraction (which can really be bad later on down the road).

Comment: Sorry - I didn't mean the polymorphism answer was wrong or bad in any way - it is indeed a very good answer. I just meant I don't want polymorphism in the problem I'm trying to solve right now, because the FoodProcessor actually knows a lot of context that the Food doesn't know.  Food shouldn't need to know about Gears and Electricity and other Foods, which are actually part of the real life problem, but not mentioned in this forum question. I accepted the "is" answer because it was the direct answer to the question asked, instead of suggesting the need to change the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
void FoodProcessor(Food food)
{
    if(food is Banana)
        ...
    else if(food is Apple)
        ...

    ...
    etc
}
```

edit: if you can use polymorphism as mentioned in the other answers, then disregard this